# Zero results in Query/GqlQuery

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

How do I know if the results of my query either using the Query interface or the GqlQuery interface returned zero results? Would using `.get()` on zero results produce an error? If yes, what's the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when doing a get() if there are no results you will have an object containing None

I normally do

```
result = query.get()
if result is None:
  #do the following
```

or if you want to check that its not none then

```
if result is not None:
  #do the following
```

Answer (score 2):

if a query returns no results, `fetch()` returns an empty list `[]` and `get()` returns `None`

in either case you can use the following:

```
if result:
    #handle the result
else:
    #no results were returned
```